# How to reduce size of a React Native Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have created a simple React Native application but the size of the application is very large when I create a build for Android, around 35mb.
How can I reduce my application's size?

I am using :

```
expo build:android
```

Comment: I think this is more of a question for something like the [React Native Subbreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/). Stack Overflow is more for finding help on specific code-related questions, rather than a broad question like this :)

Comment: Can you share the command that you are using to build your package?

Comment: I am using expo build:android

Comment: Will ask on reddit too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this :
The first one is to migrate the project to Bare React Native and then use build command or use eas feature provided by expo.
Use `eas build --platform` for building ios or android package as it optimizes the size as well.
Checkout [this link](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/) for more, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the eas command worked and I will try the other method as well.

Answer (score 1):

From your project directory, `run expo eject`

This will download the required dependencies and build native projects under the ios and android directories.

then go to android/app/build.gradle and change

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // false to true , clean and rebuild if changing
]

 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false // change to true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false // change to true
```

```
android {
splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    }
```

PS: ExpoKit is deprecated and will no longer be supported after SDK 38. If you need to make customizations to your Expo project, we recommend using the bare workflow instead.